# Firebase - Structuring the Database

Tags: ios, database, firebase

Am working on an app for iPad, to organise sports, using Firebase. 
The requirement is that:

- Each Sport may contain many events.
- Many teams would register for an event.

The queries to be handled would be:

- Displaying team names given Sports name and Event name
- Displaying details of all registered teams given Sports name and Event name

Am new to designing the database model for firebase. I have designed the firebase structure, as shown in the image.

Will this structure support my queries optimally? 
 Kindly suggest changes that I would have to make.
Thanks in advance:)

**Firebase structure**

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st**, firebase push keys have the very handy feature of sorting chronological, meaning just apply alphanumeric sort and they will be in chronological order even for offline writes.

Ideally, you design your document in such a way that you don't need to query them. *If you're coming from a MSSQL world, your documents will be analogous to MSSQL views, but with no tables to back them up.*

Or in other words, store the documents as you expect the results of your queries.

## Applying to an app

Let's suppose:

1. You have a view in your app showing the start datetime, # of teams joined, and prize, for all events in a given sport.
2. Clicking any of the events, you have a view showing start datetime, end datetime, venue, sponsors, and the team name of all teams joined.

This is essentially two nodes dedicated to such views:

[image: Firebase Example nodes]

Comment: Events > Event Key : ChildID autogenerated by Firebase

Events > Event ID : Used to retrieve the child items in the order in which they are added.  
    
Example : Event  ID will be starting from 1 and auto-incremented each time another event is added.

Comment: Firebase push keys sort chronological already, you don't need that second key.

Comment: I've updated the answer, please tell me if its clear

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed and very clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

So, what i get from your question is something like
Entities: Sports, Teams, Events
and it will be a many to many relationship between each entity but as you are dealing with non-sql based solution so you can get results for required queries with a structure similar to this one

```
Sports:{
sport_name,
id,
Teams:
[{team_name, id}]
}

Events: {
event_id
event_name
teams :
[
{team_name, team_id}
]
}
```

To get detail of every team you can have another node of teams in which you can keep all details.

So every time you need to get teams registerd for any event you can go directly to registered teams under teams node and same for the other query.